# Uploading to Google Cloud Storage (Nearline) via gsutil generates md5 signature error message

Tags: python, file-upload, md5, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I am trying to upload raw video files to Google Nearline for cold storage.
I am not a developer, so everything I've done has been according to Google's instructions found here: [gsutil instructions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil)

I've followed all steps and have gotten as far as being able to use the command prompt to upload small files to my bucket.

When I try to upload a directory, or even if I try to upload one big file at a time (1.9GB each), it uploads fine and for hours it will show me the upload process.

However, at the end when it finally shows that it has uploaded 1.9GiB/1.9GiB, it shows a Failure message.

```
Failure: md5 signature computed for local file (Hx9zie1...==) doesn't match cloud-suppli
ed digest (tZnqj2a...==). 
Cloud object (gs://filesource) will be deleted..
```

[Screenshot of command prompt error message](http://www.evernote.com/shard/s249/sh/ea0ff0b0-ef20-4aba-8a32-8161a86fc113/496c7f3d11b989dfaf4760e51f029dcb)

Anyone have any insight on why I'm seeing this error message and what the best method is to upload using gsutil?

Comment: This site "stackoverflow.com" is intended for questions directly related to programming. Your question would be more appropriate on the site "superuser.com". Try asking your question there.

Comment: Does this happen with every file you upload or has it only happened once?

Comment: Can you send mail to gs-team@google.com with this information?  This issue can occur during certain long-running transfers; the gsutil team is working on fixing it for a future release.

Comment: I believe this has to do with the checksum. There is some documentation on how to specify the **Content-MD5 header** when copying files [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp#checksum-validation). You can run `gsutil hash file.mxf` to get the md5 hash and then try to upload the file using `gsutil -h Content-MD5:md5hash cp file.mxf gs://your-bucket`.

Comment: @rein I've found that uploading one a time will usually work. Before I had 5 command prompt windows running.

Comment: @Vaqar Thanks. I will read through it and try that.

Comment: @TravisHobrla Will do.

Comment: @Greenz Apologies. Will do so in the future.

Comment: One more thing to try would be to try to upload files using the **-m** option. This will perform a parallel copy:
`gsutil -m cp -r dir gs://my_bucket`

Comment: @JeffLi when you had 5 command prompt windows running, were they copying different files or portions of the same one?

Comment: @Vaqar I did try that. It took a couple of days to upload and in the end, there was also an error. I don't remember the exact error message though. I am trying that again right now with a smaller folder..hopefully that will work.

Comment: @rein They were 5 command prompt windows for uploading 5 different files.